# Jenkins repeatable parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Is there a way how to create repeatable input parameters in Jenkin build with the possibility to add/remove them?

something similar to this:

[image: repeatable parameters]

I'm creating my input parameters in Groovy, and I need a list of 2 inputs:

```
properties ([
  parameters ([
    string(name: "NAME", defaultValue: ""),
    string(name: 'VALUE', defaultValue:"")
  ])
])
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate /clarify what you mean in your first sentence?  "repeatable input parameters" and "the possibility to add/remove them?". Per build or per job? UI, dsl, groovy?

Comment: I have the groovy script for a project build which consists of 2 parameters (see above), for a new requirement we need to have an array of that 2 parameters., so I'm asking if there's a way to add/remove input parameters for a build created in groovy.

Answer (score 1):

**No** -- the number of job parameters is fixed.

Your best bet is to use a single string parameter that supports multiple values (separated by some separator) and to convert that string to an array in your job.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately using a single parameter with multi values isn't an option, will cause more issues then it solves